# jquery how to count divs in row with different class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I'm pretty weak in JS and I'd like some help resolving an issue.

I want to count the number of `td` elements and add class `something(n)` to every row's `td` element. (n) - is the number of td in each row. How can I do it? Please help.

I have code:

```
<table>
    <tr class="five-1">
        <td>
            something           
        </td>
        <td>
                something2      
        </td>
        <td>
            something3          
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="five-2">
        <td>
            something1          
        </td>
        <td>
            something2          
        </td>
        <td>
            something3      
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Take a look at `length` and `addClass` of jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please keep in mind this site is NOT for "write this code for me". Please show us what you have tried so far and where you are having the issue. Although this is a simple problem and I am sure someone will give you an answer, if this was a complicated issue then it would of gotten closed for off-topic

Comment: `$('td').addClass(function(i) { return 'something' + i })`

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! We will gladly help you, but you have to show some research and effort first, and when you get stucked, you post the specific issue

Comment: you should put that as an answer @adeneo cuz it is correct

Comment: Sorry... but the problem is I even don't know what to do... shall I use FOR loop for it? Tryed...
`for (x=0; x<tr.length; x++) {
  tr[x] = $('td').each(function(i,n){ $(n).addClass('y-' + (i + 1));});` but its not working.

Comment: @NellaN - You probably won't even need to do that... If those classes are for styling, you can call each `tr` using `tr:nth-child(x)` on the CSS side... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('tr').each(function(){
        $('td',$(this)).each(function(ind) {
           $(this).addClass('something' + ind);
        });
     });
   });
</script>
```

This way you first select all TRs (in all tables on the page, if you want to do it only in a specific table, add an id or class to that table) then using the each function select all TDs in that row then add a Class to every TD.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cfjumovs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Give your table a class or Id (if there is more than one..)

```
<table Id="myTable">
<tr class="five-1">
    <td>
        something           
    </td>
    <td>
            something2      
    </td>
    <td>
        something3          
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="five-2">
    <td>
        something1          
    </td>
    <td>
        something2          
    </td>
    <td>
        something3      
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then Javascript

```
var rows = $('#myTable td');
$.each(rows,function(i, r)
{
     $(this).addClass('cellclass' + i)          

});
```

Comment: It is not ***required*** to give a class... How about `$("table td")`?

Comment: and what if there is more than one table?

Comment: Oh... so you should rephrase: *Give your table a class in case there's more than one*...

Comment: Couldn't you just do `$('td').addClass('something')`? I thought about making this an answer, but shied away

Comment: Yeah mate that would work, provided you don't have more than one table.  If there was more than one table it would do this for all cells in all tables.